# Override SimpleMessageListenerContainer.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false) behavior

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

We have been using a framework to use Spring AMQP , where the framework has set the SimpleMessageListenerContainer.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false),

Which means default messages will not be Requeued if throwing an exception from consumer .

Is there any way i can change this behavior without changing the  SimpleMessageListenerContainer.setDefaultRequeueRejected(true)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean can you set the container to not requeue by default but requeue for some exception, the only way you can do that is to set `defaultRequeueRejected` to `true` (the default) and use a custom error handler.

The default `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler` is configured with a default `FatalExceptionStrategy` that treats certain unrecoverable exceptions as fatal (message conversion exceptions etc). When these exceptions are thrown the message is rejected and not requeued.

You can provide a custom `FatalExceptionStrategy` to the error handler and (since  version 1.6.3) inject an instance of a subclass of `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.DefaultExceptionStrategy` and implement `isUserCauseFatal()` - this allows you to decide which exceptions are fatal (reject and don't requeue) and which should be requeued. The error handler achieves this by throwing `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` which is a signal to the container to not requeue the message.

Prior to 1.6.3, you had to inject a complete implementation of `FatalExceptionStrategy`.